# requests post restart docker container

Tags: docker, python-requests, urllib

i am using docker container to call API with Python Requests.

once i call an endpoint it terminate the container
logs

> DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): testing.com:8200
>
> [2020-03-08 14:43:16 +0000] [1] [INFO] Handling signal: term

i expect the second line in log will be like

> ```
> DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://testing.com:8200 "POST /api/Users/Login HTTP/1.1" 200 None
> ```

but the container closed before the expected line
if i call the API without docker it seems good

Answer (score 0):

i founded the solution the endpoint which i called takes the container id and stop it